# Multiple list show hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a way to show a larger image within a `div` when its related thumbnail is selected. below is an example of what I'm trying to do with either jquery, javascript or html5. what method would work best for a layout like below

```
<div id="show_area">
 show large non-thumb image here
</div>

<!-- selection list -->

<div id="view1">
 <div class="info">
  <span>Product: Info</span>
  <span>Description: Info</span>
 </div>
  <a href="#"><img src="/thumb.jpg"></a>
</div>

<div id="view2">
 <div class="info">
  <span>Product: Info</span>
  <span>Description: Info</span>
 </div>
  <a href="#"><img src="/thumb.jpg"></a>
</div>

<div id="view3">
 <div class="info">
  <span>Product: Info</span>
  <span>Description: Info</span>
 </div>
  <a href="#"><img src="/thumb.jpg"></a>
</div>

<div id="view4">
 <div class="info">
  <span>Product: Info</span>
  <span>Description: Info</span>
 </div>
  <a href="#"><img src="/thumb.jpg"></a>
</div>

<div id="view5">
 <div class="info">
  <span>Product: Info</span>
  <span>Description: Info</span>
 </div>
  <a href="#"><img src="/thumb.jpg"></a>
</div>

<div id="view6">
 <div class="info">
  <span>Product: Info</span>
  <span>Description: Info</span>
 </div>
  <a href="#"><img src="/thumb.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to show it inside the div or in a "popup"/dialog window?

Comment: @Sergio inside a div which will be to the left of the list

Comment: Do you plan on loading the larger image when the thumbnail is clicked? Or are all of the images already loaded?

Comment: Do you use same src as the thumbnail or another URL?

Comment: @Sergio images same location just image_thb.jpg and image.jpg as the full

Comment: do you have an alternate large image , or do you wish to have the thumbnail viewed large

Comment: Check my corrected answer

Comment: @SarathSprakash i have an alternative large image.

Comment: from where you to get the alternative image url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('img').on('click',function(){
    var old_img = this.src;
    var new_img =old_img.split('_thb').join('')
    $('#show_area').html('<img src="'+new_img+'" />');
});
```

An example [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/XWFL8/)

Comment: You need also jQuery loaded in your page for this, so add `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` inside your `<head>` tags.

Comment: would adding `$('#list img')` instead of `$('img')` help prevent any image wrapped in a achor from triggering the script?

Comment: @acctman, yes, exactly. Then it would be just anchor inside #list

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('a img').click(function() {
    $('#show_area img').hide();
    $('#show_area img').attr('src','https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-v0soe-ievYE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAABSw4/fNj-YFu4lgw/s120-c/photo.jpg').stop().fadeIn();
});
```

get the alternate image `src`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/2MkVY/